# ActiveMQ Artemis send message without creating producer connection

Tags: producer-consumer, activemq-artemis

Is there any solution to send message to ActiveMQ Artemis queue without creating producer? I want to send byte message via consumer connection.

There is a `QueueControlImpl` class but for send byte message it must be encoded, and I don't want to encode message.

```java
Object queueControlObj = server.getManagementService().getResource(ResourceNames.QUEUE + queueName);
QueueControlImpl queueControl = ((QueueControlImpl) queueControlObj);
String msg = Base64.encodeBytes(message.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
queueControl.sendMessage(null, Message.BYTES_TYPE, String.valueOf(bytesMessage), false, "", "");
```

I hope to find a solution to send a message to a Destination without creating new connection for the producer.

Comment: Why are you using the `QueueControl` (which is part of the _management_ interface) to send a message? You'd be much better off using an actual messaging client to send a message instead.

Comment: Thanks Justin, Because i don't want to create new connection for producer,all of consumers are in one node and we plan to send message to destination queue  by consumer session. i found session.getConnection().sendCommand(messageDispatch) . is it better than QueueControl ?

Comment: What kind of connection are you using for your consumers? What client library are you using? What protocol are you using? Please provide details or your question can't be answered with precision (or perhaps at all).

Comment: The `sendMessage` operation on the `QueueControl` is not meant to be used from a messaging application. It is exposed for _management_ operations and is used, for example, from the web administration console that ships with the broker. Messaging applications should use a _messaging_ interface (e.g. JMS) to send messages.

Comment: in server we use embedded activemq artemis 2.19.1,and config openwire and mqtt acceptors.

Comment: clients used activemq-client and connect via javax.jms.connection , in server i used a OpenWireInterceptor to get consumers information such as session and consumerInfo

Comment: Why can't your JMS clients use the same `javax.jms.Connection` to ultimately create both their `MessageConsumer` and `MessageProducer` objects?

Comment: this session.getConnection().sendCommand(messageDispatch) is org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.openwire.amq.AMQSession from consumers.((OpenWireConnection) remotingConnection).getSession(sessionInfo.getSessionId());

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256435/discussion-between-justin-bertram-and-fereshte).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Justin for your valuable tips. My main problem was not creating a new connection for the producer to reduce the load on the network. Since I'm using `Embedded ActiveMQ Artemis`, Justin suggested using `in-vm connections`.